# Images in the Render Layer nodes of the Compositor disappear

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

Images in the Render Layer nodes of the compositor disappear each time a new layer is rendered. It only keeps the most recent rendered image. The other layer nodes are blank.

I've set up my scenes with layers correctly and the compositor setup is correct with the different layers. 
The rendered layers show in the Image Editor.
Compositing is checked in the Post Processing options.
Transparent option is checked.
RGBA is checked for alpha channels.

I've searched for answers but no luck. I've wasted too much time trying to solve this.

[image: Compositor setup]

[image: Each layer with the same settings, but different layers]

Comment: Do you mean there is no data from other render layers except for the render layer added last after Blender finishes compositing? Note that in your render layers settings only 1 scene layer is enabled which means objects from other layers won't be rendered at all

Comment: It is one scene but rendered separately in 4 layers. I just can't get it to composite into one final scene.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my scene rendered repeatedly when I press F12?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69960/why-is-my-scene-rendered-repeatedly-when-i-press-f12)

Comment: In order to use the layers, they have to b e active in the scene (visible).

Answer (score 1):

OK solved. I was manually rendering each layer and the compositor was only reading the last render, which was whatever layer I had just done. I let the compositor do the work and it handled it.